# ¿Por que sale me sale error 1822 en MySQL

Tags: mysql

> (Error Code: 1822. Failed to add the foreign key constraint. Missing index for constraint 'line_ibfk_3' in the referenced table 'product')

```
CREATE TABLE vendor(
v_code INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE,
v_name VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
v_contact VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
v_areacode CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
v_phone CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
v_state CHAR(2) NOT NULL,
v_order CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(v_code));

CREATE TABLE product(
p_code VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
p_descript VARCHAR(35) NOT NULL,
p_indate VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
p_qoh SMALLINT NOT NULL,
p_min SMALLINT NOT NULL,
p_price NUMERIC(8,2) NOT NULL,
p_discount NUMERIC(5,2) NOT NULL,
v_code INTEGER,
FOREIGN KEY(v_code) references vendor (v_code) ON UPDATE CASCADE);

CREATE TABLE customer(
cus_code INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
cus_lname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
cus_fname VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
cus_initial CHAR(1),
cus_areacode CHAR(3) NOT NULL,
cus_phone CHAR(8) NOT NULL,
cus_balance INTEGER NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE invoice(
inv_number INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
cus_code INTEGER NOT NULL,
inv_date VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(cus_code) REFERENCES customer(cus_code)); 

CREATE TABLE line(
inv_number INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
line_number INTEGER NOT NULL,
p_code VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
p_qoh SMALLINT NOT NULL,
p_price NUMERIC(8.2) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(inv_number) REFERENCES invoice(inv_number),
FOREIGN KEY(p_code) REFERENCES product(p_code),
FOREIGN KEY(p_qoh) REFERENCES product(p_qoh),
FOREIGN KEY(p_price) REFERENCES product(p_price));
```

Answer (score 0):

Añade estas dos instrucciones SQL antes del último `CREATE TABLE` y lo resolverás:

```
ALTER TABLE product ADD INDEX(p_price);
ALTER TABLE product ADD INDEX(p_qoh);
```

Recuerda que para, para establecer una clave ajena, el campo referenciado debe estar, como mínimo, indexado. El resto de requerimientos: `NOT NULL`, `UNIQUE` o `PRIMARY KEY` ya dependen de tu diseño. Pero, al menos, indexado.